# NaN error when trying to sum numerical inputs

Tags: javascript, html

The purpose of this program was to take the calorie amount for food items entered and then compute the total calories. I didn’t do much math to get NaN as result, but that is the error that pops up.
I expected the sum of the elements that are entered in the calorie input box.
I think it must be a small error, thank you for your help.
Also, when I run it on here there is some error, could you please help me with that also,

```js
var i=0;
var tot_cal=0;
var ar=[];
var arr=[];

function sheet(form){

    var a=new Object();
    a.food=document.getElementById("fooditem").value;
    a.cl=document.getElementById("calorie").value;
    a.cal=parseInt(a.cl,10);

    for(var h=0;h<20;h++)
     ar.push(h*2);

    for(var h=0;h<20;h++)
     arr.push(2*h+1);

    i=localStorage.getItem("ui");

    alert(typeof a.cal);
    localStorage.setItem(ar[i],a.food);
    localStorage.setItem(arr[i],a.cal);

    document.write(i);
    document.write("<br><br>");

    i++;
    localStorage.setItem("ui",i);

    for(var j=0;j<i;j++){
        document.write("<br><br>");
        document.write(localStorage.getItem(ar[j]));
        document.write("   -   ");
        document.write(localStorage.getItem(arr[j]));
        document.write("<br><br>");

     }
    document.write("click add more to add more food items or press button click");


    document.write('<a href="./data.html">Add more</a>');
    document.write('<button onclick="total()">Click me</button>');
}

function total(form){
    for(var h=0;h<i;h++){
        tot_cal=tot_cal+parseInt(localStorage.getItem(arr[h]),10);
    }

    document.write(tot_cal);
}
```

```html
<html>
<header>DATA</header>
<body style="text-align:center">
<form name="data" method="post" onsubmit="return sheet()"><br><br>
Name of the Item:<input type="text" id="fooditem" value=""><br><br>
Calorie content:<input type="number" id="calorie" value=""><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) doesn't do what you think it does, don't use it.

Comment: Take a crash course in the DOM https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Comment: it seems that 'ui' doesn't have an initial value in the local storage, then I don't know what will do the first call to : i=localStorage.getItem("ui");

Comment: this is cause of `parseInt(localStorage.getItem(arr[h]),10)` undefined. find out all the values.

Comment: `1+undefined` gives `NaN` in result. Similar thing happening in your situation.Check value undefined or not

Comment: @Kaushik ty, without using parseInt if i do the sum they are getting concatenated,n when i checked  typeof it showed string,thats y i used parseInt. can u suggest a method

Comment: after `parseint` check if it is not `nan` then add else ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make some changes in the way you are writing your HTML. 
As you are not using form that you have passed in the sheet function your form. When a submit button is clicked, the data inside the form are sent to the server.

The action attribute of the form determines the URL where the data will be sent in this case it just reloads.

To accomplish post use can make an ajax call inside your sheet function.

```
<html>
<header>DATA</header>
<body style="text-align:center">
<div style="display:flex; justify-content:center"><p>Name of the Item:<p><input type="text" id="fooditem" value=""></div><br><br>
<div style="display:flex; justify-content:center"><p>Calorie content:</p><input type="number" id="calorie" value=""></div><br><br>
<input type="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="sheet()">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="poc.js"></script>
</html>


var i=0;
var tot_cal=0;
var ar=[];
var arr=[];

function sheet(){

    var a=new Object();
    a.food=document.getElementById("fooditem").value;
    a.cl=document.getElementById("calorie").value;
    a.cal=parseInt(a.cl,10);

    for(var h=0;h<20;h++)
        ar.push(h*2);

    for(var h=0;h<20;h++)
        arr.push(2*h+1);

    i=localStorage.getItem("ui");

    alert(typeof a.cal);
    localStorage.setItem(ar[i],a.food);
    localStorage.setItem(arr[i],a.cal);

    document.write(i);
    document.write("<br><br>");

    i++;
    localStorage.setItem("ui",i);

    for(var j=0;j<i;j++){
        document.write("<br><br>");
        document.write(localStorage.getItem(ar[j]));
        document.write("   -   ");
        document.write(localStorage.getItem(arr[j]));
        document.write("<br><br>");

     }
    document.write("click add more to add more food items or press button click");


    document.write('<a href="./data.html">Add more</a>');
    document.write('<button onclick="total()">Click me</button>');
}

function total(form){
    for(var h=0;h<i;h++){
        tot_cal=tot_cal+parseInt(localStorage.getItem(arr[h]),10);
    }

    document.write(tot_cal);
}
```

Working link: https://codepen.io/akshat_03/pen/JqQpwG

Answer (score -1):

It seems there is some logic issue in setting arr[0] th value. Thats why you are getting NaN value.